# How to change background color of unselected JavaFX ListCell

Tags: java, javafx

So I use a JFX`ListView` to display all the connected friends. I've changed the background colors of the cells. But on border color i cant find. You can easily see it, if you control+click an already selected row, it deselects it and then you can see the two blue border colors. How do I change this so it fits with the rest of the background???

This is the css that changes the colors.

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-border-width: 2 0 2 0;
    -fx-border-color:#37474f;
}
.list-cell:even:hover {
    -fx-border-color:linear-gradient(to left, #DF1721, #cd005f) ;
}
.list-cell:odd:hover {
    -fx-border-color:linear-gradient(to left, #DF1721, #cd005f) ;
}
.list-cell:even:pressed {
    -fx-fill: linear-gradient(to left, #9c1017, #8f0042);
}
.list-cell:odd:pressed {
    -fx-fill: linear-gradient(to left, #9c1017, #8f0042);
}
.list-cell:hover:empty {
    -fx-border-color:#37474f;
}

.list-cell:hover:selected {
    -fx-border-color:#ff4d4d;
}
.list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #4b5960;
    -fx-border-color:#ff4d4d;
}
```

So here you can see an unselected `ListView`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the -fx-background-insets that causing the blue lines when focused. Include the below code to fix it.

```
.list-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-insets:0px;
}
```